# How to have a list of a given day for the last 10 years replacing non business days by nearest Monday

Tags: sql-server

With this :

```
Declare @MyDate Date
Set @MyDate = '2017-08-12'
```

I would like to get a table like this:

> Where the Non Business days are replaced by the nearest Monday

I have a Table called **Holidays** that have only the Dates that I consider non-business. Thank you for your help.

```
DateID    Date
1       2016-08-12
2       2015-08-12
3       2014-08-12
4       2013-08-12
5       2012-08-13
6       2011-08-12
7       2010-08-12
8       2009-08-12
9       2008-08-12
10      2007-08-13
```

Here is Holiday Table to be considered like a Saturday or a Sunday

`Holbiz
2016-01-01
2016-02-15
2016-05-30
2016-08-12`
 2016-08-12 is only for the sake of this example

Comment: Is it essentially that you want the nearest Monday for a given date?

Comment: When it's a Saturday, a Sunday or included in my Holiday Table; Otherwise I want the actual day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @d date='20170812';
with
  a as(
    select dateadd(yy,-1,@d) d,0 i
      union all
    select dateadd(yy,-1,d),i+1 from a where i<9
  ),
  b as(select d,datediff(dd,0,d)%7 dd from a)
select iif(dd<5,d,dateadd(dd,7-dd,d)) from b;
```

[Check it](http://rextester.com/MOT92407).

Comment: That works perfectly. Now if one of the dates in the results is included in my Holidays Table like:
Let's Friday 2016-08-12 is in my Holiday Table, how can I replace it with Monday 2016-08-15?

Comment: @Rich I think ^ that is another question,No?

Comment: If I can insert a statement into the query to make sure the results are not in a Holiday Table that would be part of the same query.

Comment: @Andrei I went back to your solution as another solution was deleted, I'm afraid as a neophyte I might have done something he did not like. On your solution, by adding this `CASE WHEN exists (select HolBiz from Holidays where HolBiz = d ) then  dateadd(d, 1, d) else d end` I had your solution working fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want exactly , but if I understand you , this will work for you:

```
Declare @MyDate Date;
Declare @Temp Table (DateID INT IDENTITY(1,1) , [Date] Date);
Declare @Interval int =1;
Set @MyDate = '2017-08-12';

while @Interval <= 10
begin
if datename(dw,DATEADD(yy , -@interval , @MyDate)) not in ('Sunday' , 'Saturday')
  insert into @temp([Date]) select  DATEADD(yy , -@interval , @MyDate)
      else
         if datename(dw,DATEADD(yy , -@interval , @MyDate))  = 'Saturday'
          insert into @temp([Date]) select DATEADD(DD,2, DATEADD(yy , -@interval , @MyDate) )
              else
                insert into @temp([Date]) select DATEADD(DD,1, DATEADD(yy , -@interval , @MyDate) )  ;
  set @Interval = @Interval +1;
end
Select * , datename(dw , [date]) DayName from @Temp;
```

The result:

```
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| DateID |        Date         |  DayName  |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
|      1 | 12.08.2016 00:00:00 | Friday    |
|      2 | 12.08.2015 00:00:00 | Wednesday |
|      3 | 12.08.2014 00:00:00 | Tuesday   |
|      4 | 12.08.2013 00:00:00 | Monday    |
|      5 | 13.08.2012 00:00:00 | Monday    |
|      6 | 12.08.2011 00:00:00 | Friday    |
|      7 | 12.08.2010 00:00:00 | Thursday  |
|      8 | 12.08.2009 00:00:00 | Wednesday |
|      9 | 12.08.2008 00:00:00 | Tuesday   |
|     10 | 13.08.2007 00:00:00 | Monday    |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: There is no solution without a loop?
That's the general idea plus I would need to add a statement to take in account that if the Date is include in Holidays Table I add 1 day and then re-loop. Correct?